# How do I run migrations and add a phonenumberfied as well

Tags: django-models, django-forms, migration, django-migrations, django-database

I am creating a django modelform with a phone number field in it. I've pip installed the phonenumber field module and added it to my installed apps but now when I try to run migrations to add the form with this field to my database. I get this error. What am I doing wrong.

```
File "C:\Users\houst\CMS\TheMachine\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\houst\CMS\TheMachine\manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\houst\Envs\Mach\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 
419, in execute_from_command_line  
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\houst\Envs\Mach\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 
413, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)     
File "C:\Users\houst\Envs\Mach\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in 
run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\houst\Envs\Mach\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in 
execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\houst\Envs\Mach\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in 
wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\houst\Envs\Mach\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 149, in handle      
loader.project_state(),
File "C:\Users\houst\Envs\Mach\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 335, in 
project_state
return self.graph.make_state(nodes=nodes, at_end=at_end, real_apps=list(self.unmigrated_apps))
File "C:\Users\houst\Envs\Mach\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 315, in 
make_state
project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
File "C:\Users\houst\Envs\Mach\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 89, 
in mutate_state
operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
File "C:\Users\houst\Envs\Mach\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", 
line 80, in state_forwards       
state.add_model(ModelState(
File "C:\Users\houst\Envs\Mach\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 373, in 
__init__
 if field.is_relation and hasattr(field.related_model, '_meta'):
AttributeError: 'PhoneNumberField' object has no attribute 'is_relation'
```

this is my model.py

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField

class Profile(models.Model):
 Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
 Address_Line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
 Address_Line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
 Postcode = models.IntegerField()
 State = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 Area = models.IntegerField()
 Email = models.EmailField()
 Country = models.CharField(max_length=300)
 State_Region = models.CharField(max_length=100)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.Name + ' ' + self.State_Region
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Appear, Performance, Profile2, Publicity, Bookings, Profile
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField

class Profiles(forms.ModelForm):

   phone_number = PhoneNumberField()

   class Meta:
      model = Profile
      fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably solved it by now (or gave up), but just in case: The problem is that you are putting a *form field* into the model, but you need a *model field* there. It's confusing, it happens all the time. It should work if you change the import in your models.py to `from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField`.